# Devise a definition of $x^2$ which is an injective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the simple function of multiplying a number times itself. I am interested in knowing more about the kind of groups which may be devised over which this function is an injective homomorphism. The most trivial among these, I would say, is where we define the function $x^2:(\mathbb{R}^{+}/\{0\},\times) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{+}/\{0\},\times)$, where $\times$ of course is elementary multiplication. This corresponds to cutting-off half the graph like was done in school for $x=y^2$. But what are some more exotic groups?

**Requirements**

- $|\ker x^2| = 1$
- Operation preservation
- Domain, codomain should be groups (or not, go crazy)
- Definition must roughly correspond to squaring a number in some meaningful way (this is intentionally open-ended)
- Challenge: no graphs

I am currently reading about the theorems of homomorphisms and I wanted to gain more insight into the sort of groups/structures I should expect to see going into my future courses. This is not a homework problem. I will also post here anything I find for fun though I totally expect to be outclassed. Thank you.

Comment: The group is $C_3$, the cyclic mult. group of order 3. The map is $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: As long as the group is abelian, the map $x \mapsto x^2$ is always a homomorphism, where $x^2$ is $x \ast x$ for whatever group operation.  For example, choose $a \neq 0, 1$, then $a^n$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, forms an abelian group of numbers.

Comment: $x\mapsto x^2$ is not injective on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Two examples: finite abelian groups of odd order and complex roots of unity of odd order (an infinite group)

Comment: Any abelian group that has no element of order $2$.

Comment: Also, $x\mapsto x^2$ is a homomorphism $G \to G$ iff $G$ is abelian